# snipe command isn't mentioning user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a snipe command but the only problem is it doesn't mention a user properly. I've been trying to solve this for so long. I also attached a picture of what the snipe looks like.
**Traceback Error:**

Ignoring exception in command snipe:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 261, in snipe
embed = discord.Embed('description = f"<@!{snipe_message_author} deleted `{snipe_message_content}`')
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
smc = []
sma = []

snipe_message_content = None
snipe_message_author = None
snipe_message_id = None

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author
    global snipe_message_id

    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.id
    snipe_message_id = message.id
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    if message.id == snipe_message_id:
        snipe_message_author = None
        snipe_message_content = None
        snipe_message_id = None
    

@client.command()
async def snipe(message):
    if snipe_message_content==None:
        await message.channel.send("Theres nothing to snipe.")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name= f"<@!{snipe_message_author}>")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mention users in the author field or the title field, better move it to the description.

```py
embed = discord.Embed(description = f"<@!{snipe_message_author}> deleted `{snipe_message_content}`")
```

Comment: I added the new code but it gave me a pyflakes error **[pyflakes] EOL while scanning string literal**. I thought there must have been a typo in the code so I tried to fix it. So now the new code was `embed = discord.Embed('description = f"<@!{snipe_message_author} deleted `{snipe_message_content}`')`. After I tested it it gave me a huge traceback error. I'll put it up inside my original post since it's too long to post here.

Comment: fixed it, typo from "

Comment: Would I have to change anything else in the code to like the embed? Because now it's displaying this image. Image is in the original post.

Comment: edited again, and yes, you have to remove the `set_author` line